# Is it best practice for functions to return after raising an error in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a bunch of functions in packages that first check the validity of the work being requested and throw exceptions if not.

Example:

```
package body foo as
  function implode (
    i_foo_id number
  ) return implode_id as
    not_implodable exception;
    implode_id number;
  begin
    if not is_implodable(i_foo_id) then
      raise not_implodable;
    end if;
    //Implode logic here.
    return implode_id;
  exception
    when not_implodable then
      raise_application_error(-20005, 'Imploding is not possible on this foo.');
  end implode;
end foo;
```

I have turned on warning reporting and get something like this when I compile.

Warning(67,3): PLW-05005: subprogram IMPLODE returns without value at line 14.

If I put a return statement after the raise_application_error then the warning goes away. Since raising the error exits the call stack, is there any good reason to return null anyways?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. It is **not** a best practice for functions to return after raising and error in PL/SQL.

It is possible and sometimes even recommended to add code just to shut up the compiler, like:

```
exception
  when fooex then
    raise_application_error(-20100, 'invalid number');
    return null; -- silence PLW-05005
end;
```

Be sure to document such a peculiar code !

Generally I don't like a code that is just there to satisfy compiler warning, but there is always exceptions to this rule. In this particular case I'd say the problem is more the compiler than the code. In my opinion code like below is perfectly valid and compiler should not complain about it. In fact I think compiler should warn if a block has statements after `raise` as it's effectively a dead-code (unreachable code).

Let's consider the following function:

```
$ cat foo.sql 
create or replace function foo(p_in in number)
return number is
  fooex exception;
begin
  if p_in < 1 then
    raise fooex;
  end if;

  return p_in;
exception
  when fooex then
    raise_application_error(-20100, 'invalid number');
end;
/
show errors
```

Running this in Oracle 11g XE:

```
-- By default the warnings are disabled
SQL> @foo

Function created.

No errors.
```

Usually I want all warnings:

```
SQL> alter session set plsql_warnings = 'ENABLE:ALL';

Session altered.

SQL> @foo

SP2-0806: Function created with compilation warnings

Errors for FUNCTION FOO:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
1/1      PLW-05005: subprogram FOO returns without value at line 13
1/1      PLW-05018: unit FOO omitted optional AUTHID clause; default
         value DEFINER used
```

After reviewing the code I found out the warnings above are incorrect, so I disable them for this compilation unit only:

```
SQL> alter session set plsql_warnings = 'ENABLE:ALL, DISABLE:(5005,5018)';

Session altered.

SQL> @foo

Function created.

No errors.
SQL>
```

Now all is good and great.

My recommendation is to turn on all warnings by default and then turn off wrong positives per compilation unit (`alter session set plsql_warnings = 'ENABLE:ALL, DISABLE:(5005,5018)';`). If possible: `alter system plsql_warnings = 'ENABLE:ALL';` but in practice this might be a bit too harsh ...

And oh, it is a recommended practice to turn on all compiler error checks. We as a programmers need all the help the compilers can give to us ! Unfortunately with Oracle PL/SQL compiler this needs to be compromised.

Comment: Rather than `RETURN` garbage, I find it's closer to the design intent to `RAISE;` the error, which also silences PLW-05005.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to always raise any exceptions that your function (or procedure, as the case may be) doesn't know how to handle.

For example, if your function queries a table, and the logic is "if no rows are found, return 0" or something, then I'd expect your function to handle the exception and return a sane value.

If your function gets an *unexpected* exception, e.g. VALUE_ERROR (e.g. due to bad data in the table caused by some bug in a data load procedure, or a missing constraint), that's arguably *not* the responsibility of the function; I'd expect your function to propagate the exception to the caller (although I might write the function to at least log the error before re-raising the exception).

This is why you should always have a `RAISE;` in any `WHEN OTHERS` exception handler.

The only time I'd make an exception to this rule is if I'm coding an API for some legacy system which can't handle exceptions, and expects an "error flag" (e.g. as an out parameter). In that case, I might use a `WHEN OTHERS THEN` exception handler to log the unexpected error, and return the error flag to the caller. It's not good coding style though, because it puts a lot of trust in the calling code to check the "error flag" before assuming the function did its work without error.

Comment: I agree 100% with everything you say here. I rarely ever code WHEN OTHERS statements because usually if I encounter something I didn't expect up front, or some invalid data, the proper way to handle that is to let it bubble up naturally. There are a few edge cases, but those are very infrequent.

Most of the PL/SQL we write sits in between a PHP front-end, some other middle-ware we wrote, and the tables. The way our wiring works we throw exceptions in cases it would usually not be considered appropriate, but that's a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter one way or the other. Adding a return will make the whatever code validator your using happy.  The statement will never get reached as raising the application error puts control in caller's exception handler if exists or execution ends.

Personally, I code according the syntax of the language and hope the validators eventually correct their mistakes.

Comment: Also, if you did put the return there, the validator should say 'Line unreachable'.

Comment: In this case the validator is the Oracle's PL/SQL compiler.

Comment: Yeah...it's messed up. It the difference between human analysis vs artificial AI analysis.

Comment: That is my line of thinking. I am always looking to improve my code so I recently turned on showing warning. A few of the warnings have exposed some places I had left room for some potential bugs. I am thinking that the compilers inability to notice raise_application_error in function exceptions is more of an issue with the compiler than actual good advice. Thank you for confirming what I was thinking.